# How can I mock django model object?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

For example, I have a lot of interrelated tables in my project

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.models.CharField(max_length=16)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.models.CharField(max_length=16)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.models.CharField(max_length=16)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and so on.

I need to test model C and have no interest in A and B models. Is there any chance to mock model B that can be used when creating model C objects?
I mean I'd like to create few objects without building a massive base just to test one tiny model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bakery](https://github.com/model-bakers/model_bakery)

```
from model_bakery import baker
AmodelInstance = baker.make(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for some tests and you only need a few instances you could do something like this:

```
model_a_instance = A(name='somename')
model_b_instance = B(name='somename2', a=model_a_instance)
model_c_instance = C(name='somename3', b=model_b_instance)
```

Nonetheless, if you need to save model_c in the DB make sure to save model_a and model_b also.

If you are going to need these models more extensively I would recommend creating a factory class to populate your models.

Hopefully this helped.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you didn't answer the initial question, but I guess to create a factory that resolves database relations is the only way to achieve more or less the same result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of research I don't have an answer to my question, but I think I found a tool that takes care of 'preparing the base' before actual testing or greatly simplifies it.

I have about 1000 lines of test code in my project and I decided to switch to pytest and rewrite tests almost from scratch, so, I'm actually doing what I hoped to avoid, but it's acceptable for me in this case.

Instead of creating queryset objects via django ORM I utilize [Factory Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to define factories that resolve database relations in the way I want.

For the example case I would implement something like that:

```
import factory

class AFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = A

class BFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = B

    a = factory.SubFactory(AFactory)

class CFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    
    class Meta:
        model = C

    b = factory.SubFactory(BFactory)
```

So, to test C model you're just creating C model object via `CFactory.create()`, and all 'chain' stuff is handled using SubFactories.

However, example models have no any constraints, unlike real database tables. Here's an example for more descriptive answer:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(choices=(('BY', 'Belarus'), ('UA', 'Ukraine')),
                            max_length=64, unique=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Supervisor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If I would use same approach as with A B C example and executed something like `SupervisorFactory.create()` at least 2 times I violated Country.name and Employee.email constraints. 2 SupervisorFactory calls would try to create 4 countries, but it's possibly to create only 3 - 'BY', 'UA', and empty string that is factory boy's default. Thus, you should specify the rules factories generate data by:

```
class CountryFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        django_get_or_create = ('name',)

    name = factory.Iterator('BY', 'UA')

class EmployeeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee

    email = factory.Sequence(lambda nums: 'employee.%04d@employee.io' % nums)
    country = factory.SubFactory(CountryFactory)

class Supervisor(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Supervisor

    email = factory.Sequence(lambda nums: 'supervisor.%04d@supervisor.io' % nums)
    country = factory.SubFactory(CountryFactory)
    employee = factory.SubFactory(EmployeeFactory)
```

Hope this will save your time.

Comment: view on the question and this response year later - too much useless and error-prone work, just make a few fixtures with constant attributes and you'll be fine